# Representing alphabets as numbers

Tags: java

can someone help please? I'm completely new to Java Programming and I need to represent alphabets as numbers such that I can perform operations (like matching two numbers) with numbers instead of alphabets.E.g. A = 1; B = 2; c = 3;... Many thanks

Comment: `System.out.println((int)'A');`

Comment: @jlordo.. Post that as answer. You will get hell lot of upvotes.

Comment: @jlordo: That would actually be `65`, not `1`...

Comment: Use 65 for `'A'`, as it is so in most popular character encoding standards. Don't try to reinvent the wheel, see [http://xkcd.com/927/](http://xkcd.com/927/) ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println((int)'A');
```

will give you 65 (ascii code for A is 65)

```
System.out.println((int)'A' - 64);
```

will offset the number to 1.

If you want the lower 'a' to print out to 1 as well using the above method, simply turn that to uppercase with `Character.toUppserCase('a')`;

Answer (score 3):

Considering that you're new to programming, you have to know that there is something called [ASCII Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). This code describes which character is how encoded. As you can see the charachter 'a' is represented by the number 97. So in Java this

```
System.out.println((char)(97));
```

would print the character 'a'. The `(char)` is a so called cast. That means the number 97 is "forced" to be shown as a character. Vice versa you can do

```
System.out.println((int)'a');
```

This forces the character 'a' to be shown as its ASCII-number value 97.

So if you want to represent the characters from a to z by 1-26 you have to do:

```
char yourChar = 'z';
int yourCharInt = (int)yourChar - (int)'a' + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Create conversor methods like these:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();

        System.out.println(t.alphabetToNumber('A'));
        System.out.println(t.numberToAlphabet(1));
    }

    public int alphabetToNumber(char a) {
        return a - 64;
    }

    public char numberToAlphabet(int i) {
        return (char) (i + 64);
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(t.alphabetToNumber('0'));` <-- `-16`

Comment: @jlordo '0' is not an alphabet. The OP is working with uppercase alphabet characters.

Comment: From OP: `A = 1; B = 2; c = 3;` uppercase A, uppercase B, lowercase c

Comment: If it's not a typo, then, you'll have to use Character.toUppserCase, as Krispy points out.